# Click through to implementation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

With Resharper and Visual Studio, I use Ctrl+Click to go to the method, but for interface implementations, I use the context option of Go To Implementation.

Is there a way to achieve this with the Ctrl+Click behaviour - perhaps implement a variation of it, such as Shift+Ctrl+Click?

Comment: Not with the mouse, I think. If your interfaces have only one impl, then `Alt+End` will go straight there; else it will pop up a list of impls which you can cursor/enter

Comment: Useful, thanks.  JetBrains are non-committal on this: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5233727#5233727

Comment: In ReSharper 7 (VS keybindings), I can also use `Ctrl+F12`  to go to implementation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have ReSharper 8.1 installed, use [Ctrl+Alt+Click](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-336222) for "Go To Implementation" action

Comment: Good to know! I'll trial left then middle click versus ctrl+alt+click to see which I prefer.

Answer (score 1):

On the basis of [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686901/how-do-i-edit-visual-studios-mouse-shortcuts) I have mapped my middle mouse button click to Go-To-Implementation via the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+Alt+B (the IntelliJ keyboard mapping equivalent of Alt+End).

To do this I used the "Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center" app. I created an "app-specific setting" for Visual Studio, chose "Middle-tap" and selected "Key Combination".

To use it I do need to left click on the symbol in the source code first then middle click. My next challenge is remembering to use this mouse shortcut! Note that I've effectively replaced the normal middle click functionality in Visual Studio, though I only recall using this for closing tabs, which I can do via the 'x' button anyway.