# Is there a way to "bind" my Mouse4 button to "Navigate Backwards" in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The title pretty much explains the whole question. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Premium, I like the Navigate Backward command for when I right click on something and do go to definition and then I want to go back to where I was Navigate Backward works. But I'm so used to my mouse button button doing that, I've noticed I've starting using it in Visual Studio and expecting it to go back but it doesn't. I know how to change the command to a different key press, but is there a way to make it work on a mouse button?

Comment: If you have a mouse which can be programmed (eg a gaming mouse) program the button but I wouldn't know what to suggest other than that.

Comment: I do, but I don't want to do that because I want it to be a regular mouse button click. i don't want it to send ctrl+alt+f2 or that would be annoying outside of visual studio.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a (pointless) Limitation of the C++ IDE in Visual Studio. In C# the mouse buttons work as expected, but not in C++.

There are several Addins for Visual Studio to cover this functionality, I'll point you to the one that I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11148237/968531):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57119/Forward-Backward-Code-Navigation-with-the-Mouse-Th

This Add-In worked for me. I could also upgrade it to Visual Studio 2012 by simply changing the Version-Tag in the Addin-file to "11.0".

Comment: heh... thanks for the link, this is kind of crazy that the back mouse button does work in c# no issue, but man... I'm looking through a c++ library at the moment and was going bonkers trying to navigate through effectively.