# How to map Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 forward/back buttons to mouse forward/back buttons?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mouseevent, key-bindings

I have read posts about having add-ons or extra programs that listen to and respond to other buttons than the traditional left- right- middle- click functionality in a mouse. However, all of them were dedicated to version 2010 of Visual Studio. Is there any way to remap extra mouse button presses to the forward/back commands in Visual Studio 2012?

(if it helps I am using a RAT 7 [amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003CP0BHM))

Comment: I'm still on VS2010 and interested in this.  Can you link the info you've found for 2010?

Comment: Haha, I found the answer to my question inadvertently when re-searching for those links. Here is the link that you wanted, and the one I found is posted as the answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686901/how-do-i-edit-visual-studios-mouse-shortcuts

Answer (score 2):

Found a nice Mouse navigation extension. Not sure if it only works exclusively on 2012, but it does work on 2012. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/87fb8c65-d1db-49e9-a068-d62a222a4ae7

If anyone interested in the link for the info I found on 2010 stuff, here it is: [How do I edit Visual Studio's mouse shortcuts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686901/how-do-i-edit-visual-studios-mouse-shortcuts)