# Visual Studio intercepting mouse 4/5 in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio-community

I recently started using Visual Studio, and for the most part it is fine. However, I have noticed that there are some hotkey bindings while debugging associated with the mouse 4/5 buttons. I use those buttons for push to talk on my voip software. As a result, whenever I go into debug mode I can no longer talk to my coworkers.

I would very much prefer to not have to change my p2t button as it is very ingrained into my workflow at this point.

It seems that the mouse buttons are not available for rebinding via Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard

Does anyone know of a solution for this? I saw something similar [in this topic, but it is about assigning extra hotkeys and doesn't seem related to my issues.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686901/how-do-i-edit-visual-studios-mouse-shortcuts)

Comment: Do you have the Mouse Navigation extension enabled? If so, try disabling it.

Comment: I do not. It seemed irrelevant to my issues so I didn't install it. This seems to be a problem with the native features in VS

Comment: The keys have a default behavior in the operating system itself. If you're in a browser, they behave as forward and backwards. Perhaps visual studio also uses those shortcuts. I don't have VS in this machine so I can't confirm, but try looking for the command name or a key called "forward" or something. Maybe it's bound to those keys in keyboards that have them, and the mouse keys are working as if they were those keyboard keys.

Comment: yeah, I dug through the hotkey rebindings, but it didn't seem to have any mouse actions in there, only keyboard. The thing that confuses me most is that it is only a problem when I have it attached to a debugger. During normal editing there isn't an issue.

Comment: What commands are triggered when you press those buttons?

Comment: To be honest, I can't quite figure out exactly what it's doing. It seems to move through defined variables within the scope of the cursor and highlight them, but that isn't quite what it's doing. I can't figure out the pattern other than it highlights forwards/backwards certain items. Not a particularly useful function as far as I'm concerned.