# Visual studio 2019 change CTRL+ CLICK from "Go To Definition" to "Go To Implementation"

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I would like to  CTRL+ CLICK from "Go To Definition" to "Go To Implementation".

And make CTRL + Right Click "Go To Definition"

Possible?

Thanks

Comment: It is only easy to change keystroke assignments.  Add-in required: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686901/how-do-i-edit-visual-studios-mouse-shortcuts

Comment: this needs to happen

Answer (score 6):

Could not find a way to edit this but there's an extension that allow for CTRL+mouse-"middleClick" that trigger a "Go To Implementation".

MiddleClickDefinition:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=norachuga.MiddleClickDefinition

Answer (score 2):

Another option I found: Use AutoHotKey.

You can use this script to intercept Ctrl + Left mouse click and change it into Ctrl + F12 only inside visual studio:

```
#IfWinActive, YourAppName - Microsoft Visual Studio
^lbutton::^F12
```

I used the window inspector tool in AHK to see the name of my visual studio window. In my case I only need this for a specific project so it only runs when inside that exact window name.